# how to calculate no of rows deleted as I loop through records in php

Tags: php

am using the code below to loop and delete records from database. Please i will like to count the number of rows deleted as the code loops. any idea will be appreciated

```
$post_ids = intval($_POST['post_id']);

foreach($post_ids as $id){
    // Delete record
// I will sanitize for sql injection attack later
    $query = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE id=".$id;
    mysqli_query($con,$query);
}
```

Comment: a query inside a loop is almost always a bad thing, you could group the ids `$query = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE id IN(1,2,3,4);`

Comment: Your code will not work. The output of `intval` is an integer, not an array, so you will get an `Invalid argument for foreach` error. Is `$_POST['post_id']` an integer or an array?

Comment: @tim it's possible there may be no posts for a given id value, in which case `count` will overestimate the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just delete them all at once and then call `$deleted = mysqli_affected_rows($con);`

see the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php).

Comment: if I delete them all at once. then how do I count the number of rows deleted which is the purpose of this post.

Comment: What martin is saying, mysql keeps an internal record of how many rows were affected by the last call. You can fetch that number with the answer above.

Comment: @NancyMooree "affected" can mean inserted, updated or deleted rows... always depending what the last query before calling it was. it's just important to call it immediately.

Comment: @NancyMooree also, have mysql do the loop instead with something like  `$query = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE id IN (". implode(",", $post_ids) .");";`